# Binomial Expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Please give me feedback on my answer to this question.
Question:
For all $ n\geq1:\binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{2}+\binom{2n}{4}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2k}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2n} $
  is equal to $ \binom{2n}{1}+\binom{2n}{3}+\binom{2n}{5}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2k+1}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2n-1} $.
Answer:
False, since;

Let $a=1,
 b=-1$
 and $n=1$
 ,$k=0$
  , using Binomial expression.

$$(a+b)^n=
 \sum
  \binom{n}{k}
 a^{k}b^{n-k}$$

Then $(1+-1)^{2(1)}=\binom{2}{0}1^{0}(-1)^{2-0}+\binom{2}{1}1^{1}(-1)^{2-1}+\binom{2}{2}1^{2}(-1)^{2-2}=\binom{2}{0}-\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{2}$

Thus :For all $n\geq1:
 \binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{2}+\binom{2n}{4}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2k}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2n}
  \ne \binom{2n}{1}+\binom{2n}{3}+\binom{2n}{5}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2k+1}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2n-1}$
 .

Comment: Please typeset this.

Comment: A proof that the result is **true** can be produced using ideas contained in what you wrote. Note that $1+(-1)=0$.

Comment: @user142943: You are *almost* using TeX correctly, but leaving out the $\$$ signs around TeX expressions. Please see how your previous post was edited, or this one once somebody does it.

Comment: It looks like you're saying that the two sums are **unequal** for **all** $n\ge1$? Then how come for $n=3$ I get $\binom 60+\binom62+\binom64+\binom66=1+15+15+1=32$ and $\binom61+\binom63+\binom65=6+20+6=32$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\displaystyle(1-1)^{2n}=0=\{\binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{2}...\}-\{\binom{2n}{1}+\binom{2n}{3}...\}$$

$$\implies \{\binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{2}...\}=\{\binom{2n}{1}+\binom{2n}{3}...\}$$