# odd/even binomial coefficient identity

Tags: induction

For all n\geq1
 :

$$\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
4
\end{matrix}\right)
  + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2k
\end{matrix}\right)
 + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2n
\end{matrix}\right)
 $$

is equal to

$$\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
1
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
3
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
5
\end{matrix}\right)
  + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2k+1
\end{matrix}\right)
 + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2n-1
\end{matrix}\right)
 .$$

MY SOLUTION

Binomial Formula : (a+b)^{2n}
  = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}
 \left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
k
\end{matrix}\right)
 a^{k}
 b^{n-k}

let a=1
  , let b=-1
  , let n=2

(1+(-1))^{2(n)}
 = \left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)
 -\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
1
\end{matrix}\right)
 +...\mbox{-}\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2n-1
\end{matrix}\right)
 +
 \left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2n
\end{matrix}\right)

(1+(-1))^{2(4)}
 = \left(\begin{matrix}2(2)\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}2(2)\\
1
\end{matrix}\right)+\left(\begin{matrix}2(2)\\
02
\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}2(2)\\
2(2)-1
\end{matrix}\right)+
 \left(\begin{matrix}2(2)\\
2(2)
\end{matrix}\right)

0=1-4+6-4+1

0=0

Thus for all n\geq1
 :

\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
4
\end{matrix}\right)
  + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2k
\end{matrix}\right)
 + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2n
\end{matrix}\right)

is equal to

\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
1
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
3
\end{matrix}\right)
 +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
5
\end{matrix}\right)
  + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2k+1
\end{matrix}\right)
 + \ldots
  +\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\
2n-1
\end{matrix}\right)
 .
Can anyone please give feedback and tell me if my solution is correct.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807423/binomial-expression

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  For formatting mathematics don't forget that you need dollar signs "\$x\$" if you want the expression to occur inline, double dollar signs "\$\$x\$\$" if you want it on a line by itself - see my edit.  Also, please try to choose a readable title ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
From binomial formula $$(1+x)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}x^k$$ for $x=-1$